# Salesforce Knowledge mobile page link goes to summary page

Tags: appexchange, knowledge

We have a scenario where we have a mobile enabled website. There is a link to a Salesforce KB page:

http://kb.lendingclub.com/investor/articles/Investor/Can-I-still-make-individual-orders-if-I-have-a-PRIME-account

Somehow it detects that the page is being access from a mobile device and adds the pkb_mobile# to the URL like this:

http://kb.lendingclub.com/investor/pkb_mobile#/articles/Investor/Can-I-still-make-individual-orders-if-I-have-a-PRIME-account

Now that link does not go to the article but rather goes to the general article page listing all the articles. Somehow the url needs to be transformed as the correct url is:

http://kb.lendingclub.com/investor/pkb_mobile#article/l:en_US/kA0500000000FsdCAE/s

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue being tracked [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0ByAAI). No workarounds known as of now.